# Parse string into double

Tags: java, parsing

My code doesn't seem to work when the string token is an int. Here it is:

```
public class CO2Data {

    CO2Data dataSet[] = new CO2Data[10];
    String strLine = "Italy 476.08  116.86  2   592";
    int lines = 10;
    double roadCO2;

    public void saveLineInfo(String strLine, int lines) {
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(strLine);
        String str = "hello";
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                str = token.nextToken();
                if (count == 3) {
                    getRoadCO2(str, roadCO2);
                    dataSet[i].setRoadCO2(roadCO2);
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    public double getRoadCO2(String str, double roadCO2) {
        roadCO2 = Double.parseDouble(str);
        return roadCO2;
    }

    public void setRoadCO2(double roadCO2) {
        this.roadCO2 = roadCO2;
    }
}
```

In the rest of the lines, roadCO2 is a double, so I'm guessing my program is getting confused? How do I fix it? Thanks so much!

Comment: You may want to add a tag for this for the actual language you are using. It looks like Java, but it could be one of may different languages. Also, the scoping for roadCO2 is a mess within the getRoadCO2 function...

Comment: Is this C# or C++??  Also is your question concerning the variable roadCO2 or does it concern the parameter "String strLine"?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Please post a sample input and the actual/desired output.

Comment: USA 5951.13 1530.3 5.16 777
UK 2573.4 119.68 1.99 470
Error: null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at CO2Data.main(CO2Data.java:56)
***Line 56: System.out.println(dataSet[1].country);** (the data at the beginning is the 2 lines that work being printed before it crashes on Italy)

Comment: There is no way to tell what is causing `NullPointerException` at line 56 of your original program (possibly the system out println) looking at the code you have given us. Only reasonable explanation is that `dataSet[1]` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting NullPointerException because,

You've declared an Array of `CO2Data dataSet[] = new CO2Data[10];`,
but every element inside this `CO2Data[] array` is pointing to Null.

Hence, this call: `dataSet[i].setRoadCO2(roadCO2);` will generate a `NullPointerException`
because `dataSet[i]` is pointing to `null`.

Solution :

Instantiate `dataSet[i] = new CO2Data();`
then call `dataSet[i].setRoadCO2(roadCO2);`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend changing the names of the parameters to your methods to something slightly different than the class datamember "roadCO2".  That might help you sort out the error :)

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code, I got a NullPointerException at line 22. This is beacuse the array 'data' has not been initialized.

You can initialize your array as follows

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    dataSet[i] = new CO2Data();
}
```